# Is the island on the Xbox one version of Subnautica

Tags: xbox-one, subnautica

My friend and I was just playing Subnautica. Markiplier was playing Subnuatica and he found an island.

Is the Island on the Xbox One version?

Answer (score 4):

The *Subnautica* world / map is not randomly generated. All geography is the same for each player and each version of the game, so yes, the Floating Island is in the Xbox One version.

(Beware that this makes the core activity of the game — exploration — vulnerable to spoilers.)

Answer (score -4):

I've tried all directions in both Survival and Creative. My game doesn't have either island. All I found was a ghost reaper and a heart attack.

Comment: If you encountered a ghost leviathan, you're already on the latest version, which means the islands are definitely there. You just went the wrong way.